# How to apply a function over a list using previous outputs as arguments?

Tags: haskell, fold, iterated-function

I have a function `f :: (a -> a) -> a -> ((a -> a), a)`. (In the specific case `a` is `Int`, but that is irrelevant.)

I have a function `initial :: a -> a`, and a list of inputs (`inputs :: [a]`).

I need to apply `f` to all the elements of `inputs`, but, for each, I need to take the `fst` part of the output of the previous iteration and feed it as the `(a -> a)` part of the input for the next. As the output, I need to have a list of type `[a]`, which is the `snd` part of the outputs of each iteration.

How can I recursively apply `f` to the `fst` part of the output and the elements of `inputs`, while building up a list of the intermediate `snd` parts of the output?

Comment: what have you tried already - as of now this sounds like a homework/exercise - we would be doing for you. us where your tries are failling

Answer (score 3):

You may like `mapM`. Below I give it the type it has, a specialization of that type, the newtype unwrapping of the specialized type, and a further specialization. The final type should look quite familiar to you. I use `~::` to informally mean "approximately has the type".

```
mapM  :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
mapM  :: (a -> State s b) -> [a] -> State s [b]
mapM ~:: (a -> s -> (s, b)) -> [a] -> s -> (s, [b])
mapM ~:: (a -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a, a)) -> [a] -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a, [a])
```

The last type describes exactly what you want to do: it can take (a slightly modified) `f`, `inputs`, and `initial` as arguments, and produce the list of outputs (along with some auxiliary information).

Comment: great answer for a) not containing spoilers, and for b) providing insight to advanced haskellers as well

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like  `scanl` could help:

```
scanl g (initial, undefined) xs
  where g (i,_) a = f i a
```

To remove the initial element from the result list (which will always be 1 longer than the input list), apply a `tail` to the result.

Comment: Perhaps throwing a `tail` out front would eliminate the danger of empty lists.

Comment: Indeed, scanl returns a list that is always 1 element longer than the input list.